# Error export php a Excel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

estoy tratando de exportar una consulta Mysql, desde php, pero al correr el código me arroja el siguiente error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\FlorNacional\export.php on line 55

antes tenia en el while  {$resul['NSemana']}  me bajaba el archivo excel, pero vacio sin

La consulta en Mysql me trae resultados

Este es mi código

```
$sql="select idBaseCausales,NSemana,TFlor,Bloque,Muestra,Variedad,Acaros,Afidos,Babosa,Botrytis,Fusarium,Hetero,Minador,Trips,Trozador,Velloso,Abierto,DosPuntos,Amarillamiento,CabezaPeque,Corto,Debil,Decolorado,Deformado,Delgados,PetaloQuemado,PuntasQuemado,Rajado,Torcido,Toxicidad,ano,TInternacional 
from flor_nacional.basecausales where ano = ".$ye.";";
$resul=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

$excel = "
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>idBaseCausales</th>
        <th>NSemana</th>
        <th>TFlor</th>
        <th>Bloque</th>
        <th>Muestra</th>
        <th>Variedad</th>
        <th>Acaros</th>
        <th>Afidos</th>
        <th>Babosa</th>

    </tr>
";
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resul)){
    $excel = $excel. "
    <tr>
    <td> $resul['idBaseCausales'] </td>
    <td> $resul['NSemana'] </td>
    <td> $resul['TFlor'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Bloque'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Muestra'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Variedad'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Acaros'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Afidos'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Babosa'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Botrytis'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Fusarium'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Hetero'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Minador'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Trips'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Trozador'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Velloso'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Abierto'] </td>
    <td> $resul['DosPuntos'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Amarillamiento'] </td>
    <td> $resul['CabezaPeque'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Corto'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Debil'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Decolorado'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Deformado'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Delgados'] </td>
    <td> $resul['PetaloQuemado'] </td>
    <td> $resul['PuntasQuemado'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Rajado'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Torcido'] </td>
    <td> $resul['Toxicidad'] </td>
    <td> $resul['ano'] </td>
    <td> $resul['TInternacional'] </td>   
    </tr>";
}
$excel = $excel. "</table>";
header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-type:   application/x-msexcel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=basecausales.xls"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
echo $excel;
```

Answer (score 1):

No estás concatenando correctamente los `$result` con los `<td>`.
Para que sea aceptado, deberían concatenarse de este modo:

```
<td>".$resul['idBaseCausales']."</td>
```

Cierras el `<td>` con `"`, lo sigues con . y añades el `$result` a continuacion.
Esto es por que, una parte sería html y otra php.

```
<tr>
    <td> " . $result['loquesea'] . " </td>
<tr>
```

Comment: Hola Excorpion , ya lo he concatenado, sin embargo me da ahora este error

<td>".$resul['idBaseCausales']."</td>

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\FlorNacional\export.php:55 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\FlorNacional\export.php on line 55

Comment: Si tu problema ha cambiado, por favor abre otra pregunta con el nuevo problema.

Comment: Pd. el error nuevo, tiene que ver con que está retornando mal los valores de la query. Por favor recuerda marcar esta y seguimos en el otro.